# Inline styles on every p tag?

Tags: html, html-email

Do I need to specify the font family on every p tag in my html email using inline styles?

Or can it be specified on just the body tag?

What is best practice here to work across most email clients?

Comment: This is in no way a question for StackOverflow. A simple search of SO or Google would have given you the same answer and more reasons to make styles in-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its need to be on each tag. Windows outlook 2013 sometimes ignore style from the header